# Чтение из файла по строкам при помощи класса StreamReader(Windows Forms c++)

Tags: c++-cli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]не могу прочитать содержимое файла по строкам,так как не знаю каким методом воспользоваться,в теории не нашёл,то есть мне надо прочитать по строкам как в консоли пока файл не пуст(eof).
    Мне нужно прочитать содержимое файла по строкам следующим образом:
к примеру есть строка 5 6 7 21 45 в файле мне нужно прочитать по числу и произвести какие-либо действия.
 1.

```
 private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
int j,r;
StreamReader^rd = File::OpenText("Filer.txt");
 while(!rd->EndOfStream){
            gh = rd->ReadLine();
            int n = System::Convert::ToInt32(gh);
            j = sqrt(n);
            if (n == j * j&&prov(j)) {
                r += 1;
            }
        String^io = System::Convert::ToString(r);
        textBox2->Text = io;
    }
```

Comment: После `while` забыта открывающая скобка `{`?

Comment: да согласен,но хотелось бы узнать как прочитать строку идущих подряд чисел по одному числу 56 8 34 6 к примеру если я записал в файл их таким образом

Comment: В вопрос, пишите всю информацию в вопрос. Добавьте туда, как именно выглядит текстовый файл. И отформатируйте код.